# Using Kate's terminal plugin, how can I clear the terminal's history?

Tags: kde, command-line, kate, konsole

I want to clear all the history that I can scroll to,  so that I start with a terminal without anything in it exempt the prompt. clear only creates a clear screen, but does not delete the scroll history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>

Works for normal terminal and also the kate plugin :)

Oops I had originally put <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>... too late at night it seems

Comment: :D I was already wondering about myself

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbf> works too (for me)

Comment: well, `Ctrl+l` (that is a lower case "L")

Comment: maybe I misread the question -- anyhow, Ctrl+Shift+x does not work for me from within Kate